# Change all values of dictionary with tuple keys in python

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples

I am currently trying to change all values in a large dictionary (to the negative). I would like the statement to be in one line. I have the following dictionary sample:

```
dict = {(0,0): 1, (2, 4): 2}
```

What I want is

```
newdict = {(0,0): -1, (2, 4): -2}
```

I first tried several variations

```
newdict = {x: -x for x in dict}
```

However, I get always got the following error

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'tuple'
```

I need something that is able to loop through the tuple keys to change all the values.

Comment: `newdict = {key: -val for key, val in dict.items()}`

Comment: `newdict = {x: -your_dict[x] for x in your_dict}` or `newdict = {k: -v for k, v in your_dict.items()}`. Also, do not use `dict` as a variable name, you don't want to shadow built-ins...

Comment: `x` in your example is the key. You want to negate the value.

Comment: Oh, wow! I feel silly. Thanks! I'm new to python and forgot that you could use key and val in that way.

Comment: If you found an answer useful, feel free to accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set your value in the dictionary to be the negative of the *key* in the old dictionary rather than the negative of the *value* in the old dictionary. As such, you are trying to set it as the negative of a tuple. A tuple doesn't have a "negation" operator so you get that `TypeError`.

What you want is, like the comments mentioned, something like:

```
    newdict = {key:-dict[key] for key in dict}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @zwer mentioned in the comments above, the most efficent way to do this using only one line is to use the following code:

```
newdict = {x: -your_dict[x] for x in your_dict}
```

How this works is you are first creating a new dictionary called `newdict`.

When you declare the dictionary you use `{x: -your_dict[x] for x in your_dict}`.

What this does is uses a for loop inside of the curly brackets (which tells the compiler it is a dictionary) that will set all of the values.

The reason you were getting a TypeError is because you can not use the negative operator, `-`, on a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

```
newdict = {x: -x for x in dict}
```

`x` is from `dict`, OK? It means that `x` is a *key* from your dictionary. Keys in your dictionary are *tuples*, so `x` is a *tuple*. So `-x` is an error (as unary operator `-` is not defined for tuples).

What you wanted is changing `values`, not `keys`. So one possible solution may be

```
newdict = {x: -dict[x] for x in dict}
```

as the original value of the key `x` is `dict[x]`.